# CodePlex's icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

At [Get a Stack Overflow Careers profile!](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one), the CodePlex's `favicon.ico` is used. But it's only 16x16px. It should be at least 64x64px. Use this image instead:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeplex.com](https://www.codeplex.com/Images/codeplex.png))</sub>

---

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I can't see that page, as I've already got one. Could you show it *in situ*? Does it *need* a larger image? Are other icons used, and are they larger?

Comment: @jonrsharpe http://i.imgur.com/x8wUNzZ.png

Comment: ...in the question? (And yes, that does look pretty bad!)

Comment: This appears to be specific to a browser. In Chrome it appears correctly, in Firefox it does not. The URL to the image is: http://www.codeplex.com/favicon.ico?v=21691a7af7ba  In Chrome it returns an image that is 256x256. Firefox gets a 16x16 favicon.

Comment: You are very generous.  Just to be sure: did you acquire a license that lets you give away that artwork for free?  Details, details.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know, but it was the first image I got from Google.

Comment: Just to note: we would only use officially sanctioned images - "first image I got from Google" isn't enough ;p But; interesting question: why does firefox get the wrong image? (ponders) - do CodePlex hate firefox? edit: hmm, I've sniffed the http, and it isn't CodePlex - they return the same bytes; it is FireFox itself doing random scaling

Comment: Well you can contact them and ask if they allow to use that image.

Comment: FYI, Firefox isn't scaling anything, that's an actual Windows Icon file, with separate bitmaps embedded for 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, and 256x256. Firefox is picking the smallest, Chrome the largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've actually deprecated this page with a recent change to how people get Careers profiles a few days ago. Shouldn't be an issue now.